# Publishing db information linked to rds on GitHub

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-rds, endpoint

I added it to the gitignore file incorrectly, so the db information file linked to aws rds was uploaded on the github.
The db information code is as follows.

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: "endpoint~~",
  user: "~~",
  port: "~~",
  password: "~~",
  database: "~~",
});
```

Also, I am more anxious because I received the following mail from gitguardian.
I don't even know what this means.
[image]

Will that code leak cause aws to be hacked and lead to huge billing?
I'll be waiting for the reply.
thank you.

Comment: just go change your credentials, maybe move the endpoint if it's public and you're concerned.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can I know exactly what you mean?

Comment: your credentials (username, password, endpoint) were apparently made public. This means anyone can potentially access those secrets, and depending on your security practices, access/disrupt your data or services. There are a couple of ways to handle that. The most effective is to simply make the credentials that were leaked no-longer-valid. You would accomplish this by changing the username, password, and potentially endpoint of your database host. Additionally you'll need to move to an approach that doesn't require committing secrets to your codebase directly. Hope that helps.